# What mysql returns when there is no result from the query? the word 'null' or nothing in the row?

Tags: mysql, null, mysql-workbench

For example, a table has a column with primary id 1,2,3,4,5.
What it will return if I write "select id from table where id = 6"? nothing in the row or null in the row?

Also, when I was doing the leetcode problems and sometimes getting errors, it shows my output values: [[null]]. I wonder if this means nothing is returned in my output and it caused the error. After I used ifnull(column, 0.00), the error is gone.

I am testing with mysql workbench, and there is always a row of nulls returned even though there should be no results from the query. I learned this is for inserting values. So the bench did not return anything actually, right?

Can someone clarify this for me?

Comment: there is no "row"  It returns nothing.

Comment: It will return 0 rows.

Comment: I don't use MySQL Workbench, but I very much doubt it's returning a row of nulls. That may just be a placeholder so you can add rows to the table.

Comment: that is only Workbnch that will show the "empty" if the resultaset has o records, it will show NULL only if it returns actually a NULL value,l so the interpreation of the side is that when no rows are returned it will have NULL as result